# Redis Sets Performance Issue

Tags: performance, redis, architecture, query-performance

I am trying to benchmark my redis SUNION command.
While benchmarking one of the sets contains ~ 1000 elements and other contains ~10 elements.

The order of execution is around 0.52 ms per call.

Is this performance ideal or am I missing out on some tuning settings in the conf file.

I am trying to implement tag filtering on objects using basic sets operations.
For ex.
`obj1 -> {id - 1 colour red location x}`

`obj1 -> {id - 1 colour red location x}`
`obj2 -> { id - 2 colour yellow location y}`
`obj3 -> { id - 3 clolour red location y}`

in order to store i am using sets for storing object ids for each dimensions.hence

`colour:red -> {1,3}`
`colour:yellow -> {2}`
`location:x -> {1}`
`location:y -> {2,3}`

This enables me to expose apis on top of this like : 
objects coloured red in location x
objects coloured red in any location

each of these actually translates into multiple sets operations for me using union intersection diff which i have implemented using pipelines.

Scale : 
The max number of elements inside any set is very less ~ 5000. And latency is the main point consider. If there is any other way that i should take to achieve this kind of performance. Would be helpful.

Comment: It would be impossible to say if that performance is 'ideal' or not without knowing what is the purpose of that `SUNION`. Please elaborate on why you are using the sunion and maybe we can suggest if there is another/better way of doing it.

Comment: @UroshT. added it in the description you can have a check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the performance is ideal (sounds great, less than 1ms is great in my book, but it really depends on your requirements).

I've performed the below test on my laptop:

```
$ for i in `seq 0 999`; do redis-cli sadd s1000 forbar$i; done
...
$ for i in `seq 0 9`; do redis-cli sadd s10 foobar$i; done
...
$ redis-benchmark SUNION s1000 s10
...
100.00% <= 56 milliseconds
1171.37 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark SUNION s1000
...
100.00% <= 57 milliseconds
1062.70 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark SMEMBERS s1000
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
3300.33 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark SINTER s1000
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
3311.26 requests per second

...

127.0.0.1:6379> INFO
# Server
redis_version:999.999.999
redis_git_sha1:4e5e0d37
redis_git_dirty:1
redis_build_id:abfc1e37fd7acbf7
redis_mode:standalone
os:Darwin 17.7.0 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:kqueue
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:4.2.1
process_id:23596
run_id:73b0f2f6795eccb8286fc086c83d89da45314ce2
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:55429
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:9775394

...

Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.2 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP114.0184.B00
  SMC Version (system): 2.29f24
```

These results (and some digging into the code) show that:

1. SUNION is slower than just getting the members of a set (SMEMBERS uses the same implementation as SINTER).
2. Iterating and replying with 1000 elements takes at least 17-19ms
3. The difference between SUNION and the others is not in orders of magnitude, which is good, but perhaps requires some optimizations in the Redis code (at least for this edge case).

Comment: What do you suggest as an alternative. If i could try out with something else. I have added what i am trying to achieve in the description.

Comment: How did you achieve these stats: tried running your benchmarks :
These are my stats 
99.98% <= 113 milliseconds
99.99% <= 114 milliseconds
99.99% <= 115 milliseconds
99.99% <= 116 milliseconds
100.00% <= 117 milliseconds
100.00% <= 118 milliseconds
These stats are on a mac pro with 16gigs of ram

Comment: Updated my answer with the details.